# Server-side ASPX button fails to execute method that is specified as the OnClick attribute's value

Tags: c#, asp.net, server-side, server-side-scripting

Here is the information about my development environment:

-Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013

-.NET Framework 4.0

-( 1.11.3 ) jquery.min.js

-( 1.11.2 ) jquery-ui.min.js

In our application, we have an aspx page with the following Server-side ASPX button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success btn-sm"
Text="Update" OnClick="UpdateBankRecord" ValidationGroup="valGroup" />
```

In our code behind C# file, we have the following method:

```
protected void UpdateBankRecord(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        Page.Title = "Update Bank Record";

   }
```

Sadly, the method is Not executed when the button is clicked, could someone please tell me what code modifications I need to make in order application to execute the method?  Also, could some please explain what the problem actually is?

Comment: Does the request arrive at the Server or is it not sent at all? You can check this by putting a break point in Page_Load. Also, you could try to remove the ValidationGroup from the button.

Comment: No, it's Not even reaching Page_Load, and I did remove ValidationGroup.  Also, I added CausesValidation=false to the Button server-side tag.

Comment: Does it have something to do with configuring that ASPX page and/or the said Server-side ASPX button control with the AutoPostBack attribute?

Comment: Do you do anything special in Javascript? To test, you could place another button on the form with a new Id, no CSS class and assign the same event handler. Alternatively, Remove the jQuery links temporarily.

Comment: Do you use an UpdatePanel?

Comment: No, we are not using any UpdatePanel.

Comment: We figured out the problem, it was some javaScript file used by our UI designer that deals with toggling.  The said javascript file was preventing the invocation of the server-side method.